# Django datetime comparison returning None - Why?

Tags: django, datetime, comparison

I've spent hours trying to figure this one out to no avail.. Any idea why this problem is happening??

models.py

```
from datetime import date, datetime

class Product(models.Model):
    use_activation_date = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True

    @property
    def is_active_by_date(self):
        if self.use_activation_date:
            if datetime.now() < self.activation_date:
                return False #is not active because current date is before activate date
            else:
                return True #is active because date is = or past activation_date
        else:
            return True #is active because not using activation date
```

template.html

```
                {% if not product.is_active_by_date %}
              <!-- here is the problem, it is not returning True nor False! -->
                  {{ product.is_active_by_date }} <!-- getting blank result here -->
                  Product is not active 
                {% else %}
                  {{ product.is_active_by_date }}
                  Product is active
                 {% endif %}
```

The problem happening is, whenever product.use_activation_date = True , `{{ product.is_active_by_date }}` returns True; however once the property gets to the datetime comparison line: `if datetime.now() < self.activation_date` something wrong happens and None is returned. I tried printing out datetime.now() and self.activation_date and they both display in an equal format e.g. "Nov. 18, 2015, 10 a.m." and everything looks fine..

What is going on ??  Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Comment: in the false case, what do you see if you just output `{{ product }}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the template engine is swallowing an error in the property. Try accessing `product.is_active_by_date` in the view to see what it returns.

If you have [timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts) enabled, you should use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Product(models.Model):
    @property
    def is_active_by_date(self):
        if self.use_activation_date:
        if timezone.now() < self.activation_date:
```

Comment: oh good thought! just tried that and it gave me an error: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
Thanks! That should be a good pointer for me

Comment: What did you try? Accessing `product.is_active_by_date` in the view, or changing the method to use `timezone.now()`? Do you have timezone support enabled (check if `USE_TZ = True` in your settings)?

Comment: both, when I tried accessing `product.is_active_by_date` it gave me that error, then I switched `datetime.now()` to `timezone.now()` and it solved my problem! It works perfectly thank you very much!!